# Sql statement select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given tables

```
station table
id | name
1  | Train A 
2  | Train B 
3  | Train C
4  | Train D
```

country table

```
id |  name
1  | country A
2  | country B
3  | country c
4  | country D
```

trainCountry table

```
idTrain | idCity
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 4
2       | 1
2       | 4
3       | 2
3       | 3
3       | 4
4       | 1
4       | 2
4       | 3
4       | 4
```

thiere are many trains and many countries , and there 4 trains that will pass to each country. each train has its path for example train A can pass from country A to B to C. train B can only pass from country A to B . I need to get the train that has only the path from country B to country C which are Train C and train D.
I tried it by using this sql statement but i didn't get the right record :

```
select *
from cityTrain ct
where ct.idC = (select id from city c where c.id = 2 OR c.id = 3)
```

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text, please.)

Comment: thiere are many trains and many countries , and there 4 trains that will pass to each country. each train has its path for example train A can pass from country A to B to C. train B can only pass from country A to B . I need to get the train that has only the path from country B to country C which are Train C and train D

Comment: Hey, edit your question and specify the result set instead!

Comment: I assume the same table names and column names from your data. in that case, select s.* from station s,traincountry t where t.idcity in (select id from country where id in (2,3)) and t.idtrain = s.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use group by and having:

```
SELECT idTrain
FROM trainCountry 
WHERE idCity IN (2,3)
GROUP BY idTrain
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idCity) = 2
```

This will get you all the trains that passes in cities 2 and 3.

Another way is to use exists:

```
SELECT idTrain
FROM trainCountry t0
WHERE idCity = 2 
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM trainCountry t1
    WHERE t0.idTrain = t1.idTrain 
    AND idCity = 3 
)
```

Comment: correct but what does (HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idCity) = 2) exactly do ?

Comment: The having clause filters aggregated results. count(distinct idCity) = 2 means both cities have been found.

Comment: so you put count(distinct idCity) = 2 because you know how many rows you have. our example is 2 rows. if we do not know how many rows we have ?

Comment: You want to get all the trains that stops in these specific two cities, hence count(distinct idCity) = 2. If you want to get all the trains that stops in cities 1, 2, 3, and 4, you'll change the 2 to 4 and the condition in the where clause from in(2,3) to in(1,2,3,4).

Answer (score 1):

```
select idTrain from traincountry where idCity=2
intersect
select idTrain from traincountry where idCity=3
```